# What happens to Glass timeline items when a user actually doesn't own a Glass device?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

A Glassware service can ask for (and receive) authorization to update the Glass timeline for a Google account even if the Google account is for a user *who does not own a Glass device*.

**What happens to timeline items that are inserted into a "device-less" timeline? Are there any error codes or indications that a timeline item will not be delivered because the user has no device?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone with a Google account has a timeline on the Mirror API.

If they have Glass, new items within the timeline are delivered, but at their core, a user's Mirror API timeline and their Glass device are separate entities.

There's no way to determine if a timeline item has been delivered to Glass, but that is a reasonable request. You should consider requesting it as an enhancement to the API. You can do this by filing it in this [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: Even if you dont have a glass you can download the some of the most important google glass apks and run in your android phone, where you can see the time line. Google glass is not a must

Answer (score 0):

Timeline items will sit in the cloud, waiting for the user to activate a Glass unit against that account to receive it. There is currently no way to determine if the user has Glass or not.

There have been some discussion about work-arounds and how to handle this, and you should probably star the related issue: [Request how many devices (if any) an authorized user has access to](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=107)